# Wordpress Performance- Google Compute Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, google-compute-engine, wpallimport

I am using WPMU installation and trying to import listing in my site.

I started with ns1-standard 1 (2 CPUs and 3.75GB RAM) instance of GCE. At that time import was going smoothly and I was able to import at a pace of 250 entries per hour using WP All Import.

However, that time CPU utilization went to 60-70%, which create a huge impact on live visitors on my server so I upgraded to ns1-standard-2 (4CPUs and 7.5GB RAM) and then to 11GB RAM.

Slowly performance of the import has started decreasing. I modified values of max vars, memory, max execution time to practically Infinite but now after just 15k entries speed is 80 entries in an hour. I have to import 200k entries in my server.

I am also getting sudden spikes in CPU usage. I did not have such spikes in the beginning. Also error log doesn't have anything mentioned wrt import process.

Screenshot:

[image]

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try looking at top, oprofile, or other tools to determine what is going on with the machine that is taking the time. top can also help you determine whether RAM or CPU is the issue, and can provide much more granularity than the graph you're showing from the GCP web console. (You could also try out Stackdriver in the Basic tier to get more detail on the resource utilization, which might help you figure out the spikes).

One note - you say you're using an n1-standard-1 with 2 CPUs and 3.75GB RAM, but that is not a combination we have. An n1-standard-1 would have 1 VCPU and 3.75, and an n1-standard 2 would have 2CPU-7.5GB.

An option to see if machine size is the limitation would be to power down the VM, change the size to something big like an n1-standard-32, restart, and see if it goes faster.

Another thing to investigate would be whether you are limited by disk performance. Note that our PD (boot disk) performance is related to the *overall* size of the disk. So if you created a very small disk, and if it is now getting full as you do more imports, it could be that you need to increase the size of the disk to get more performance.